# Can a Discriminator Column be part of the Primary Key in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, oop, orm, single-table-inheritance, doctrine-orm

I'm using [Single Table Inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/inheritance-mapping/en#single-table-inheritance) in Doctrine2 to store OAuth credentials for multiple services. I'd like to use the service's id as the primary key; however, that's not unique across all services.

I've setup the database to use the discriminator column and the service's id as the primary key, but I can't find a way to make Doctrine use the discriminator column as the key (in addition to the discriminator column). I'm using docblock annotations, and if I add the discriminator column as an @Id field I get an error:

```
Duplicate definition of column...in a field or discriminator column mapping.
```

If I only define the field as the discriminator column, any overlapping service ids update all the matching rows.

Anyway to make this work, other than just using an autogenerated it value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, the descriminator column can't be used as part of the primary key.

Why do you need STI for this use-case btw? You have to create one new class per open-id service you provide, sounds pretty annoying :-)

Comment: It's not that bad, since the individual service classes provide access to the service, they all just extend a Mapped Superclass to persist the common OAuth data. That way I relate a `$client` to various services. So after laoding a `$client` calling `$client->twitter->user->show($id)` would get a twitter user's data using the OAuth credentials of that `$client` Entity. I'm sure there are other/better ways to do this, but it's working reasonable well for now.

Comment: I would love to be able to use the discriminator as part of the PK as well: I have a use case where a table holds translations for various entities, and my ideal PK would be (languageCode, discriminator, entityId). Meanwhile, an auto-increment PK + a unique key on these 3 fields will do.