# Doctrine ManyToMany with as specific field value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a relation ManyToMany with doctrine (in symfony) that is depending on a field value.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Label")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      name="Item_Label",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="label_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $labels;
```

Here we understand that we have to get data from `Label` via the table `Item_label`

We are on table `Wine`

`Wine.id <-> Item_Label.item_id`

```
         <<< `WHERE Item_Label.item_type = 'wine'` >>>
                                   `Item_Label.label_id` <-> `Label.id`
```

So, how can i write the `WHERE Item_Label.item_type = 'wine'` in annotations ?
Or a SqlFilter (I tried but failed) ?

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Provide your entity definitions as far as i understand in `ManyToMany` relationship the joining table AKA junction table `(Item_Label)` will have only 2 fields whcih will hold the reference of two related entities no other fields should be added in this junction table to do so you need to create junction entity

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3814594/4126114) that it's not possible in doctrine.

My workaround was to add a method to my entity class as follows

```
public function foo($itemLabelRepo)                             
{                                                                          
    $found = $itemLabelRepo->findBy(['item_type'=>'wine', 'label_id'=>$this->getId()]);
    if(count($found)!=1) {                                                 
      throw new \Exception("Found non-one object from entity role");       
    } 
    return $found[0];                                                      
}
```

where $itemLabelRepo would be the repository to "Item_Label" in your case